# Does 'twink' imply a specific sexuality?

Tags: word-usage, slang

I know that *twink* is a slang term for hot young homosexual guys who do not have facial hair. This word is very common in the gay community (and their adult industry) and recently I've heard a debate about using the word *twink* for heterosexual guys who otherwise meet the criteria.

Can we use the word *twink* for heterosexual guys or does it always imply that the person is homosexual?

Comment: There is no such thing as ‘correct’ with something like this. It's a matter of social mores, not grammar. Yes, you can call a straight guy a twink if he fits the type, but he may not appreciate it very much. _Twink_ is a description of a particular type of body and looks (and to a lesser degree body language); that is not dependent on sexuality.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing now. Is *twink* something that describes a particular stereotype of a group of gay men, or is it used by the gay community to describe a particular physical stereotype that some men are attracted to?

Comment: @KitFox A twink has the physical characteristics of: thin, looks young(ish), and little to no body hair.  Mannerisms and implication of being gay, I'm uncertain of, although I always understood it to be a gay-community-only thing (like Janus says, straight guys probably wouldn't appreciate it)

Comment: @KitFox By the way, for an actual reference on physical characteristics:  [Gay Cliques Census](http://www.studiomoh.com/fun/census/results.php)

Comment: Good question. If it helps, I'm bi and I've been called a twink in the past. Even by people who thought I was straight. These days though, I'm just a little fat blob.

Comment: In the online gaming community, the word _twink_ often refers to a low-level character with high-level equipment. One might also say that this character is _twinked out_. To be honest, I've never heard it used in any other context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best answer anyone can give here is: yes and no.

First off, I would say that *twink* is more or less always used either *by* gay men or *about* gay men (or both). I have never, in my life, heard a (straight) girl refer to a straight guy as a twink (except perhaps if particularly discussing the notion of twinkhood, like we are now).

I have heard plenty of gay guys refer to other gay guys as twinks (or otters, cubs, bears, etc.); I have heard lots of lesbians refer to gay guys as twinks; I have heard *some* straight girls (mostly falling into the fag hag category) refer to gay guys as twinks, in conversation with gay guys; and I have heard gay guys refer to straight guys as twinks.

A twink is really just a type: it invokes images of a particular type of physique, look, facial features, hair style, clothing style, etc., just like terms like *hipster*, *goth*, or *yuppie* do. The particular combination of associations invoked by *twink* most commonly fall together in gay men, and the term arose in the gay community to describe those gay men primarily.

But if a straight guy fits the bill, it is not at all uncommon especially for gay guys to tell him that he’s a real twink, or such a twink. This may or may not please the straight guy in question.

In such cases, there is usually a certain level of association with sexuality inherent in the term, and I’ve often heard straight guys say things like, “If I were gay, would I be a twink?”—or gay guys say things like, “You’d be *such* a twink if you were gay”—which implies that being the type is not enough: to be a twink, you have to be gay.

On the other hand, I’ve also heard gay guys say things along the lines of, “Look at that twink over there in the corner. So hot! Too bad he’s straight”, or (less enthusiastically) “Nah, Leo<sup>1</sup> never did it for me—too much of a twink”, which implies that being the type *is* enough, and that sexuality is secondary.

Calling someone a twink implies, at least to some extent, that they ‘act gay’ (whatever exactly that means to the speaker), though it doesn’t necessarily imply that they *identify* as gay.

---

<sup>1</sup> Meaning here of course the ultimate straight twink: Leonardo DiCaprio as he looked in the mid-1990s.

Answer (score 3):

I've referred to my straight significant other as a twink, but the situation may be atypical. I am gender queer. I am chromosomally female but identify as male and lived a large portion of my life as ftm trans. I still have a vagina. So you could say that I'm a gay ftm dating a twink, or you could say I'm a het girl with identity issues dating a twink.

He's cis and het and has only been with ciswomen before me. Doesn't change the fact that he's a twink, or that he's from San Francisco and very happy to make money off his twink appearance as a club boi while still preferring vagina. He's very comfortable being type cast.